# Update multiple windows via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

My site has a timeout set, so after 15 minutes of in-activity a login screen appears asking you to refresh your session.

This works great, but if you have more than one window open on the site it means one page will be refreshed with the login details but the other one will not.

So the question is this, is there a way to execute the following code on each window open at the site?

```
$jq('#loginbox').hide()
```

Thanks for any help.  I should also state that the other windows will not be opened via JavaScript, the user could have just clicked open in new window / tab on a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other window is not opened via JavaScript, you won't be able to access it programmatically. In other words, the original window is not going to be able to call JavaScript functions on the other window.

However, the windows can share cookies if they have the same domain (if they're on the same website). So one possibility would be to have the other window poll for updates to a session cookie, which the original window could write to. Once the session cookie obtained a particular value, the other window could detect this change and react as you saw fit.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access windows you didn't open yourself with JS.

Each window should detect that it timed out and display a login dialog. If a user logs in in window A, then window B should be polling the server to detect if a session has been created, and restore itself in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Before you switch to the refresh screen (popup?) you can simply do an ajax call to the server to see the last time the user refreshed - if the user is still legitimately logged in, just reset the timer to the proper time.

Comment: no popups in the conventional way, it is all onsite in layers, but interesting approach

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who posted ideas, I went for the following solution, if anyone can enhance it and post code then I'll accept that as the answer:

```
$jq(function(){
    $jq(window).bind('blur', function(){checkloginrefreshed();});
    $jq(window).bind('focus', function(){checkloginrefreshed();});
    $jq(document).bind('focusout', function(){checkloginrefreshed();});
    $jq(document).bind('focusin', function(){checkloginrefreshed();});
});
function createCookie(name,value,hours) {
    if (hours) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(hours*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function checkloginrefreshed(){
    if (parseInt(readCookie("loginset")) == 1){
        eraseCookie("loginset");        
        $jq('#timeoutwarning').dialog("close");
        $jq('#timeoutwarning').html(TIMEOUTLOGINFORM);

        clearTimeout(timer);
        clearTimeout(timerWarning);

        setupTimers();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should accept one of the answers, I think they all pointed you in the right direction.